# How to use paths/urls/routes dynamically in vue.js/laravel components

Tags: laravel, vue.js

i'm trying to write my own blog software based on vue.js/laravel for learning purposes.

### Background

I'm asking myself how i write vue.js components in which the paths/urls are not hard coded. In the following example i have a post-listing component which lists all posts from the database. The json data is returned by a laravel api route (e.g. /api/posts)

In the listing i use a link to a laravel view (e.g. /posts/{id}) which shows the actual body of a specific post with {id}.

### Example

In laravel's api.php route file i can give a name to a specific route and use it with `route('api.posts.index')`. That's dynamic enough i guess?

#### api.php

```php
Route::get('', 'Api\ApiPostsController@index')->name('api.posts.index');
```

#### index.blade.php

```php
<post-listing postsview="{{ route('web.posts.show') }}" postsapi="{{ route('api.posts.index') }}"></post-listing>
```

#### PostListing.vue

In my vue component i refer to these properties `postsview` and `postsapi`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h2 class="title is-2">Recent posts</h2>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="post in posts['data']" v-bind:key="post.id">
        <a :href="postsview + '/' + post.slug" v-text="post.title"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["postsapi", "postsview"],
  data() {
    return {
      posts: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getPosts() {
      axios.get(this.postsapi).then(response => (this.posts = response.data));
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getPosts();
  }
};
</script>
```

### The question

Is there a "best-practice" way or at least a better approach? Somehow i'm not happy with this solution, but lacking experience, i don't know where to begin.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achive this, this are a few options that I know of.

1: Use blade to pass the route to the component

```
<component route="{{ route('route_name') }}"></component>
```

2: You can save a global variable with all the routes you have defined.

You can use `Route::getRoutes()` to get all the routes

and add it to your `window` on your front end

3: Use a library,

This library does exactly what you are looking for I think.
https://github.com/tightenco/ziggy

If find other options please let me know, this is a common issue for most laravel developers.

Comment: Thanks your for reply. Seems like i was not completely wrong with my way. I will update this site if i find another way doing it.

Comment: This really help me quickly